# How count the number of occurrences of all the values in a dictionary in python? TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, list, dictionary, collections, counter

I would like to count the number of occurrences of each first name in a dictionary (below):

This is my dictionary:

```
{'blue': ['Jules', 'Lucie'],
 'brown': ['Maxime'],
 'green': ['Maxime', 'Vincent', 'Lucie']}
```

this is my code :

```
from collections import Counter

Counter(dico.values())
```

I have this error : TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

This is the result I'd like to have:

```
Jules   1
Lucie   2
Maxime  2
Vincent 1
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

In order to count the occurrences of the values in the lists, a chaining/flattening of the lists is required:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

d = {'blue': ['Jules', 'Lucie'],
     'brown': ['Maxime'],
     'green': ['Maxime', 'Vincent', 'Lucie']}

Counter(chain(*d.values()))
```

The `chain` call transforms the lists to a single iterable with all the values, and the result is:

`Counter({'Lucie': 2, 'Maxime': 2, 'Jules': 1, 'Vincent': 1})`

Comment: You beat me by half-a-minute

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do. I misspoke. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to perform this with two tuple comprehensions too:

```
from collections import Counter
your_dict = {'blue': ['Jules', 'Lucie'],
             'brown': ['Maxime'],
             'green': ['Maxime', 'Vincent', 'Lucie']}
Counter((inner_val for val in your_dict.values() for inner_val in val))
```

**Out:**

```
Counter({'Jules': 1, 'Lucie': 2, 'Maxime': 2, 'Vincent': 1})
```